# Provisioning devices as dedicated devices using Android Management API not working

Tags: android, google-apis-explorer, android-management-api, emm

I have followed Android-Management-API [quick start](https://developers.google.com/android/management/quickstart) and successfully done all steps and provision a device with work profile mode. But when I tried provisioning devices(via QR code scan) as dedicated devices after factory reset, it fails and I do not see my device in "devices-list" under my organization. I see "device-policy" in settings>Google on device but when i click on "device policy" it shows that policy not synced and clicking "sync" manually shows "error updating policy". Can you please help if i misconfigure anything?

My policy is given below:

```
{
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "com.google.android.gm",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED"
    }
  ],
  "debuggingFeaturesAllowed": true
}
```

My QRcode is given below:

```
{
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME": "com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc/.receivers.CloudDeviceAdminReceiver",
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM": "I5YvS0O5hXY46mb01BlRjq4oJJGs2kuUcHvVkAPEXlg",
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION": "https://play.google.com/managed/downloadManagingApp?identifier=setup",
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE":{
        "com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc.EXTRA_ENROLLMENT_TOKEN": "{enrollment-token}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you had the device configured successfully, then did a factory reset and are trying to reconfigure? My guess would be that something is persisting from the first setup. Maybe not on your end. Perhaps google stores its policies with the IMEI (or some other device-specific id; not my area XD) used as a unique id?

Comment: I am saying that device is configured successfully if i provision it for work-profile mode on personal device. I can also see my device in "devices" using "Android Management API" explorer then. But when i try for dedicated device mode, i got "policy not synced" and device list is empty.

Comment: Are there any error messages while the device is provisioning or after it was provisioned? Also, have you tried provisioning other devices as well?

Comment: I have the same problem with tecno HiOS device.Other device work perfectly but only tecno hiOS cause the problem. - Dave Paurillo

Comment: I have the same problem but the opposite. I can enroll devices is owner mode just fine but have issues when it's a Work Profile.